# Tranary expression fail to evaluate undefined variable

Tags: javascript

Chrome console reports this when `b = a || 1` is invoked.

```
b = a || 1
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:5
```

When I expected the value of b should be 1.

Also:

```
x.push(a?'a':1)
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```

When I expected 1 to be pushed unto the array x.

Can someone please explain how to ignore undefined value with some syntax sugar? thx

Comment: The error is clear for me, since a is not defined. You can check if a exist in window or the object you want like `b = window['a'] || 1`

Comment: can you post your full code? 
the issue isn't with your ternary operation. It's that "a" has no value so it's crashing before the ternary operation is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `a` does not exist.  You need to declare the variable before you can use it in an expression.   However, you don't need to assign anything to it, because once it's declared, it will evaluate to `undefined` (and therefore will be falsy in the expression) by default, which is I think the behavior you were expecting.

```js
var a;
b = a || 1;
console.log('b is: ' + b);
```